# decomposition of finite dimensional group algebra

Tags: representation-theory

Its known that $D_4$(dihedral group) and $Q$ the quatrenion groups have the similar character table. Does it mean also their $\mathbb{C}G$ decomposition are identical because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed?(where $G$ is the group?). What if $\mathbb{R}G$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the decomposition of $\mathbb CG$ depends only on the *dimensions* of the irreducible representations of $G$, i.e., the column of the character table under the identity conjugacy class. In particular, we have $$\mathbb C D_4 \simeq \mathbb C Q \simeq \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \times M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb C).$$

The decompositions over $\mathbb R$ are not the same. See if you can prove that 
$$\mathbb R D_4 \simeq \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$$
but
$$\mathbb R Q \simeq \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times H$$
where $H$ is the Quaternion division algebra, $4$-dimensional over $\mathbb R$.